# how can I add depentent: :destroy when I'm using Mailboxer

Tags: ruby-on-rails

how can I add depentent: :destroy in user.rb to destroy the messages created between users by using mailboxer?

I have these tables and columns.

## | mailboxer_conversations         |

| id | subject | created_at          | updated_at          |

## | mailboxer_notifications         |

| id | type               | body | subject | sender_id | sender_type | conversation_id | draft | notification_code | notified_object_id | notified_object_type | attachment | updated_at          | created_at          | global | expires | sender_name |

## | mailboxer_receipts              |

| id | receiver_id | receiver_type | notification_id | is_read | trashed | deleted | mailbox_type | created_at          | updated_at          |

I did

(user.rb)

```
has_many :messages, :class_name => "Mailboxer::Message", :as => :sender
        has_many :receipts, -> { order(:created_at => :desc, :id => :desc) }, :class_name => "Mailboxer::Receipt", dependent: :destroy, as: :receiver

has_many :notifications, -> { where( notified_object_type: 'Assignment') },
        foreign_key: "notified_object_id", dependent: :destroy,
        class_name: "Mailboxer::Notification"
```

But it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `dependent: :destroy` at the belongs_to part of the association.

So a user `has_many :notifications` and in the notifications model it should say `belongs_to :user, dependent: :destroy`

Because now it says, if someone deletes a notification the user will be destroyed aswell.